# Setting RowHeaderView width having a textarea as component

Tags: java

I am trying to display the line numbers alongside a jTextArea.

Following is the code is used for purpose->

```
jScrollPane1.setRowHeaderView(jTextArea3);
jTextArea1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public String getText() {
        int caretPosition = jTextArea1.getDocument().getLength();
        Element root = jTextArea1.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
        text = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        for (int i = 2; i < root.getElementIndex(caretPosition) + 2; i++) {
            text += i + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        jTextArea3.setText(getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        jTextArea3.setText(getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        jTextArea3.setText(getText());
    }
});
```

(where jTextArea3 is where the line numbers are displayed and jTextArea1 is where the text is entered. JScrollpane2 contains jTextArea3).

It works fine, but at higher number of lines, there is problem->

http://imageshack.com/a/img36/737/yvhk.png (sry not yet allowed for direct image uploads)

Any help please?

PS-> I am using netbeans (just in the middle of learning java) and am using default layouts (that are auto generated by the software, this also implies default layout properties).

Comment: Can you please format your code. If you're using netbeans just hit SHIFT+ALT+F and copy and paste the code back here

Comment: So the left side, those are text areas?

Comment: yeah, basically a textarea that i assigned as rowheaderview component for another textarea.